# AWS S3 GET request signature does not match ESP32 C++

Tags: amazon-s3, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am trying to connect to S3 with my ESP32. I have a platformIO project with arduino framework on a windows machine. I know there are other SDKs but I wanted to achieve this by myself. I followed these two AWS documentations on how to properly make a HTTP Get request:
[Create a signed AWS API request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/create-signed-request.html#calculate-signature) and [Signature Calculations for the Authorization Header](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html).

I verified my SHA256 caluclations with [this online tool](https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256.html) and my HMAC-SHA256 calcs with [this tool](https://dinochiesa.github.io/hmachash/index.html)

I receive the following error `SignatureDoesNotMatch` as many others in this forum but most of them used AWS SDKs and other languages so they were not helpful to me.

This is the complete error message response (I removed the Bytes parts and irrelevant information and altered my access key):

```
<Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message><AWSAccessKeyId>AKIAZOKIXEXAMPLE</AWSAccessKeyId>
<StringToSign>
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230310T134304Z
20230310/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request
5263692f39c1379ed930dfd5c7ed75b40ba0619c7dc316bb7630152162a5d5ef
</StringToSign><SignatureProvided>
2b974103174d38e1946911813cd76aff7271f4ace1b75947b09c67487d2c39da
</SignatureProvided><StringToSignBytes></StringToSignBytes>
<CanonicalRequest>
GET
/firmware.bin

content-type:application/octet-stream
host:esp-data-exchange.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20230310T134304Z

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

Here are my canonical request (identical to AWS response),

```
GET
/firmware.bin

content-type:application/octet-stream
host:esp-data-exchange.s3.amazonaws.com
x-amz-content-sha256:e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date:20230310T134304Z

content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
```

my string to sign (identical as well),

```
AWS4-HMAC-SHA256
20230310T134304Z
20230310/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request
5263692f39c1379ed930dfd5c7ed75b40ba0619c7dc316bb7630152162a5d5ef
```

The final signature I calculate is `2b974103174d38e1946911813cd76aff7271f4ace1b75947b09c67487d2c39da` which again is identical to the response from AWS.

Finally, here my HTTP request:

```
GET /firmware.bin HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Host: esp-data-exchange.s3.amazonaws.com
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=AKIAZOKIXQTEXAMPLE/20230310/eu-central-1/s3/aws4_request,SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date,Signature=2b974103174d38e1946911813cd76aff7271f4ace1b75947b09c67487d2c39da
x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855
x-amz-date: 20230310T134304Z
```

**EDIT: Here a "minimal" example.**

- Parameters like date and time are hardcoded but are the same like above.
- Obviously, I cannot provide my keys. For the `sig_calc` I can provide the resulting hash from the first calculation where the `AWS_SECRET_KEY` is needed: `43d0ce257da1febfc3e750bb7c6eeab529041a7b69cc420a97039ce7e4e97a87`
- You need to be connected to WIFI - add your SSID and PASSWORD
- The error you get is now, that the request is outdated otherwise the calculation results are like exaplained above.

```
    #include <Arduino.h>
    #include "mbedtls/md.h"
    #include "WiFiClientSecure.h"
    #include "WiFi.h"
    
    
    String generate_hmac_SHA256_hash(const char *hmac_key, const char *payload)
    {
        /* Instantiating hash context structure */
        mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
        /* Defining hash type */
        mbedtls_md_type_t md_type = MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256;
        /* Byte buffer array for the hash result */
        byte hash_result[32];
        /* Initialize final hash string to be returned */
        String hash_str = "";
    
        /* Initialize the hash calculator structur */
        mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
        /* Setup the hash type */
        mbedtls_md_setup(&ctx, mbedtls_md_info_from_type(md_type), 1);
        /* Proivde the key used for hashing */
        mbedtls_md_hmac_starts(&ctx, (const unsigned char *)hmac_key, strlen(hmac_key));
        /* Provide the payload to be hashed */
        mbedtls_md_hmac_update(&ctx, (const unsigned char *)payload, strlen(payload));
        /* Perform the hash process */
        mbedtls_md_hmac_finish(&ctx, hash_result);
        /* Free memory allocated for has process */
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        /* Convert the bytes into a hexadecimal string */
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hash_result); i++)
        {
            /* Buffer for storing hex values */
            char hex_buffer[3];
            /* Converting the bytes and storing them in hex buffer */
            sprintf(hex_buffer, "%02x", (int)hash_result[i]);
            /* Concatenating the hex bytes to a string */
            hash_str += String(hex_buffer);
        }
    
        return hash_str;
    }
    
    String generate_SHA256_hash(const char *payload)
    {
        /* Instantiating hash context structure */
        mbedtls_md_context_t ctx;
        /* Defining hash type */
        mbedtls_md_type_t md_type = MBEDTLS_MD_SHA256;
        /* Byte buffer array for the hash result */
        byte hash_result[32];
        /* Initialize final hash string to be returned */
        String hash_str = "";
    
        /* Initialize the hash calculator structur */
        mbedtls_md_init(&ctx);
        /* Setup the hash type */
        mbedtls_md_setup(&ctx, mbedtls_md_info_from_type(md_type), 0);
        /* Start the message-digest computation */
        mbedtls_md_starts(&ctx);
        /* Provide the payload to be hashed */
        mbedtls_md_update(&ctx, (const unsigned char *)payload, strlen(payload));
        /* Perform the hash process */
        mbedtls_md_finish(&ctx, hash_result);
        /* Free memory allocated for has process */
        mbedtls_md_free(&ctx);
        /* Convert the bytes into a hexadecimal string */
        for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(hash_result); i++)
        {
            /* Buffer for storing hex values */
            char hex_buffer[3];
            /* Converting the bytes and storing them in hex buffer */
            sprintf(hex_buffer, "%02x", (int)hash_result[i]);
            /* Concatenating the hex bytes to a string */
            hash_str += String(hex_buffer);
        }
    
        return hash_str;
    }
    
    /* Step 1: Create a canonical request */
    String canonical_request(String payload, String method, String object, String query, String content_type, String bucket_name, String service, String host, String date, String time)
    {
      String payload_hash = "";
      if (payload == "")
      {
        payload_hash = "e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855";
      }
      else
      {
        payload_hash = generate_SHA256_hash(payload.c_str());
      }
      return method + "\n" +
              "/" + object + "\n" +
              query + "\n" +
              "content-type:" + content_type + "\n" +
              "host:" + bucket_name + "." + service + "." + host + "\n" +
              "x-amz-content-sha256:" + payload_hash + "\n" +
              "x-amz-date:" + date + "T" + time + "Z\n" +
              "\n" +
              "content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date\n" +
              payload_hash;
    }
    
    /* Step 2: Create a canonical request hash */
    String canoncial_request_hash(String canoncial_request)
    {
      return generate_SHA256_hash(canoncial_request.c_str());
    }
    
    /* Step 3: Create a string to sign */
    String string_2_sign(String algorithm, String date, String time, String region, String service, String hashed_canonical_request)
    {
      return algorithm + "\n" +
              date + "T" + time + "Z\n" +
              date + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/aws4_request\n" +
              hashed_canonical_request;
    }
    
    /* Step 4: Calculate the signature */
    String signature_calculation(int length, String array[])
    {
      String signing_key = array[0];
    
      for (int i = 1; i < length; i++)
      {
        Serial.println(signing_key.c_str());
        Serial.println(array[i].c_str());
        signing_key = generate_hmac_SHA256_hash(signing_key.c_str(), array[i].c_str());
      }
      return signing_key;
    }
    
    /* Step 5: Add the signature to the request */
    String authorization_header(String algorithm, String aws_access_key, String date, String region, String service, String signature)
    {
      return algorithm + " Credential=" + aws_access_key + "/" + date + "/" + region + "/" + service + "/aws4_request," +
              "SignedHeaders=content-type;host;x-amz-content-sha256;x-amz-date," + "Signature=" + signature;
    }
    
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html
    /* Create a sample request header */
    String GET_header(String object, String content_type, String bucket, String service, String date, String time, String authorization_header)
    {
      return "GET /" + object + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
              "Content-Type: " + content_type + "\r\n" +
              "Host: " + bucket + "." + service + "." + "amazonaws.com\r\n" +
              "Authorization: " + authorization_header + "\r\n" +
              "x-amz-content-sha256: e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855\r\n" +
              "x-amz-date: " + date + "T" + time + "Z" + "\r\n\r\n";
    }
    
    
    void setup()
    {
      WiFiClientSecure ota1_client;
    
      String algorithm = "AWS4-HMAC-SHA256";
      String region = "eu-central-1";
      String method = "GET";
      String service = "s3";
      String bucket_name = "esp-data-exchange";
      String aws_secret_key = "AWS_SECRET_KEY";
      String aws_access_key = "AWS_ACCESS_KEY";
    
      String object = "firmware.bin";
      String content_type = "application/octet-stream";
      String host = "amazonaws.com";
      String payload = "";
      String query = "";
      String date = "20230310";
      String time = "134304";
      String date_time = "20230310T134304Z";
      int length = 6;
    
      Serial.begin(9600);
      delay(5000);
    
      WiFi.begin("SSID", "PASSWORD");
      
      String can_req = canonical_request(payload, method, object, query, content_type, bucket_name, service, host, date, time);
      String can_req_hash = canoncial_request_hash(can_req);
      String str_2_sign = string_2_sign(algorithm, date, time, region, service, can_req_hash);
      String hash_array[length] = {"AWS4" + aws_secret_key, date, region, service, "aws4_request", str_2_sign};
      String sig_calc = signature_calculation(length, hash_array);
      String auth_header = authorization_header(algorithm, aws_access_key, date, region, service, sig_calc);
      String http_header = GET_header(object, content_type, bucket_name, service, date, time, auth_header);
      String bucket_url = bucket_name + "." + service + "." + region + "." + host;
      
      //ota1_client.setCACert(AWS_CERT_CA);
      ota1_client.setInsecure();
      ota1_client.connect(bucket_url.c_str(), 443);
      Serial.println("Test");
      ota1_client.print(http_header);
    
      // Wait for the response
      while (ota1_client.connected() && !ota1_client.available())
        ;
    
      // Read and print the response
      while (ota1_client.available())
      {
        String line = ota1_client.readStringUntil('\r');
        Serial.print(line);
      }
      ota1_client.stop();
    }
    
    void loop()
    {
      // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
    }
```

I have no clue why I get the message.

- I have also used the `request`and `AWSRequestsAuth` library from python with different user credentials (AWS_SECRET_KEY, AWS_ACCESS_KEY) but without success and with the same error message.
- I have also verified all my SHA256 and HMAC-SHA256 calculations with an online tool, which were all correct. However, it is strange that the example final signature (`f0e8bdb87c964420e857bd35b5d6ed310bd44f0170aba48dd91039c6036bdb41`) from [Signature Calculations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-header-based-auth.html) was calculated different here [this tool](https://dinochiesa.github.io/hmachash/index.html).
- I do have at least a `/` or `+` in my SECRET_ACCESS_KEYs not sure if this poses an issue

Any hints on what could cause the issue is very welcome! Trying for several days to make this work.

Comment: "which again is identical to the response from AWS", just to be clear:  This is just an echo of the signature you provided, the actual signature AWS calculates is not shown.  Can you provide a [mre] of how you're calculating the signature?  Almost by definition, there must be an issue in it, and we can only guess with the details provided.

Comment: Oh thanks regarding the signature since I had different *strings2sing* in request/response I thought it could be the same with signature. I have no problem showing my code, but there are many steps so a minimal exampel is tricky but I will try to implement one tomorrow in my question.